# plot.ksvm invert x and y axis

Tags: r, plot, svm

here is my code, the plot a obtain is OK for the region drawn by the plot function, but not for the data. the axis are OK except for the data plotted by the plot.ksvm: x and y axis are inverted. why? and how do I fix it?

```
library(kernlab) 
set.seed(77)

# sets constructions
## 1st set: uniform in a rectangle
x1.n    = 200   # number of sample
x1.ymin = -10
x1.ymax = 8
x1.xmin = 0
x1.xmax = 18
x1 <- cbind(runif(x1.n, x1.xmin, x1.xmax), runif(x1.n, x1.ymin, x1.ymax))

## 2nd set: uniform into a ball
x2.n    = 20    # number of sample
x2.c    = c(-1,3)       # center
x2.r    = 2     # radius
angles  = runif(x2.n, -pi, pi)
r       = runif(x2.n, 0, x2.r)
x2 <- cbind(cos(angles) * r, sin(angles) * r)
#plot(x2)

training.set=rbind(x1, x2)
training.label=c(rep.int(-1, times=x1.n), rep.int(1, times=x2.n))
rbf <- rbfdot(sigma=.1)
K.gaussian=kernelMatrix(rbf, training.set)
K.linear=kernelMatrix(vanilladot(), training.set)

# plot and svm
plot(training.set, col=training.label+3)
s <- ksvm(training.set, training.label,type="C-svc")
X11()
plot(s, data=training.set)
X11()
plot(s, data=cbind(training.set[,2], training.set[,1]))
```